# Autostart a GUI application in Debian as root

Tags: debian, startup

I would like to know which is the most correct way to make my Debian *automatically* start up a graphical application once the desktop has been loaded. The app must be started as root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file in your home dir called `/home/$USER/.config/autostart/my_app.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gksudo my_application
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=my_app
Comment=My comment
```

Then login again.

Comment: Obviously the user also needs to have NOPASSWD defined in `sudoers` file (my Debian installations don't have that as a default, at least).

Comment: `Hidden=true` did not work well on my Raspberry

Answer (score 2):

You should use [gksudo](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo) to start graphical apps with root rights.