# Create an example script that launch into graphical interface, to test auto start on boot

Tags: linux, window-manager

I am working on a Linux Debian server (AWS EC2) and I have a software that needs to run in a graphical environment.

If I start it manually (by typing `./program.sh` in its directory) it is working fine: i can switch to a vncviewer window (its a cloud server that i am controlling remotely) i can see the program starting.
the `$DISPLAY` value is set at boot time to `:1.0`

However if i try to have my `program.sh` to be run at boot time by creating a `init.d` script, I can see nothing happening in the graphical environment.

I have tried to read the log of my program but I couldnt find anything conclusive.

I think there is a problem either with the `DISPLAY` variable or with the xhosts permission, but because the soft I am running is a bit intricated (with login credentials etc) , it is tough for me to find the problem

That's why I would like to resort to creating a simple "`hello_world.sh`" script that would just open a simple window in the graphical env, to test what happens when starting it manually and with boot start.

Can anyone give me such a script? Its functionality should basically be: type `./hello_world.sh` in a shell -> see a window opening in the graphical environment. The purpose would be to test how that simple script behave if i create an init.d startup script for it.

---

The detail of my current non-working init.d file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          IBController
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog +vncserver
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

dir="/opt/IBController"
cmd="./IBControllerGatewayStart.sh"
user="depot"

name=`basename $0`
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid"
stdout_log="/var/log/$name.log"
stderr_log="/var/log/$name.err"

get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps -p `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already started"
    else
        echo "Starting $name"
        xhost local:depot
    export DISPLAY=:2.0
        cd "$dir"
        if [ -z "$user" ]; then
            sudo $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        else
            sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        fi
        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
    if is_running; then
        echo -n "Stopping $name.."
        kill `get_pid`
        for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
        # for i in `seq 10`
        do
            if ! is_running; then
                break
            fi

            echo -n "."
            sleep 1
        done
        echo

        if is_running; then
            echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Stopped"
            if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
                rm "$pid_file"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    if is_running; then
        echo "Unable to stop, will not attempt to start"
        exit 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
    status)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Running"
    else
        echo "Stopped"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with an init.d script as sysVInit doesn't have a graphical display when it starts the background processes.

Comment: @Raman Sailopal I have a vnc sevrer that is also started at boot

Comment: Please attach the `init.d` you created.

Comment: @Arpit Agarwal Just added it

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Environment loads after the `user` has logged in. So, `init.d` won't work because there will be no `Xserver` running.

Before trying below workaround you will also have to configure `Debian` to autologin the specified `user` so that GUI loads.

Create a `program.desktop` file inside this directory `/home/$user/.config/autostart/`. Make directory if not exists.

**program.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=program.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Porgram
Comment=Program Description
```

There are some related questions, have a look at them also.

- [Why doesn't this .desktop file run on startup? | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404040/why-doesnt-this-desktop-file-run-on-startup/404967#404967)
- [Autostart a GUI application in Debian as root | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146072/autostart-a-gui-application-in-debian-as-root)
- [Automatic root login in Debian 6.0 without GUI | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/407914/automatic-root-login-in-debian-6-0-without-gui-xserver)

Comment: thx for your reply. This is the soft i am trying to autostart: https://dimon.ca/how-to-setup-ibcontroller-and-tws-on-headless-ubuntu-in-10-minutes/ (you can skip to the section: "Make it all startup on boot!"). How do you explain it works in that example?

Comment: I also have tried simply starting the soft using `systemctl start program` i.e. after the boot, still having no luck.